# install and execute cocos2dx project on windows 8

Tags: visual-studio-2012, windows-8, windows-phone-8, cocos2d-x

I am making a small basic game for multiple mobile platforms using cocos 2dx, I have done all the coding in c++ on xcode and the project is running fine for iOS and android.

But when porting to windows phone I am facing a lot of hurdles. I am using cocos2dx 2.1.3 on visual studio 2012  express on 64 bit windows 8 with windows 8 phone SDK.

Firstly i don't get templates for cocos2dx, then there is no option to run the project in simulator or device. I have been digging the internet alot for this and have found some tutorials but all of them have one or the other limitations.

can somebody guide me with this windows part or a totally new way round to implement cocos2dx on multiple platforms ?

Answer (score 2):

### Option 1

Your going to have to open a new Direct3D project and follow the directions from [here](http://www.cocos2d-x.org/projects/cocos2d-x/wiki/Windows_Phone_8_Environment_Setup)

### Option 2

There are a couple build scripts available to generate project types for all platforms in python, as seen [here.](http://www.cocos2d-x.org/projects/cocos2d-x/wiki/How_to_create_a_multi-platform_project_in_one_command_line)
*(this works with 2.1.2 or later)*

### Option 3

Newer versions of cocos2d-x have build scripts for all platforms that come with the [latest git repos.](https://github.com/cocos2d/cocos2d-x) Not sure if there are a lot of breaking changes but the newer versions also have build projects.*(build-win32.bat)*

#### About the project template.

The templates for windows 8, at least in the last stable release I looked at a month ago, still had some issues with the html in the `c++ project wizard` but, the current development branch should have that fixed for the windows 8 visual studio browser. If they haven't then there are a couple of html `meta-data` tags that will need to be removed as they are depreciated in order for the project wizard to be usable.